# use class variable of child in method of parent such that variable can be changed dynamically (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, oop, html5-canvas

I am making a web page with fish moving in the background.  I have a parent class called Fish and child classes for each species of fish.  The Fish class has a print method which I want to reference a variable used commonly by each instance of the species class.  I need to resize the images on the fly so I would like to simply modify the variable for the species and have each object of the species adjust.  My question is:  How do I create a single variable for each class which can be used by each instance of that class within a parent class method?

Here is a simplified version of what I have tried.  Of course it doesn't work.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <body>
          <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
     </body>
     <script>

          function Fish(fi){
               this.myPic = fi;
          }
          Fish.prototype.print = function(cnv, x, y){
               cnv.drawImage(this.myPic,x,y);
          };

          function clownF(){Fish.call(this, clownF.pic);}
          clownF.prototype = Object.create(Fish.prototype);
          clownF.prototype.constructor = clownF;
          clownF.pic = new Image();
          clownF.pic.src = "clownF.png";

          clownF.pic.onload = function(){
               var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
               c.width = 500;
               c.height = 300;
               var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

               var f = new clownF();
               f.print(ctx,10,10);

               var temp = document.createElement('canvas');
               temp.width = clownF.pic.width / 2;
               temp.height = clownF.pic.height / 2;
               var tctx = temp.getContext('2d');
               tctx.drawImage(clownF.pic,0,0,temp.width,temp.height)
               clownF.pic = temp;

               f.print(ctx,100,100);
          }
     </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe something like this: http://elegantcode.com/2011/01/19/basic-javascript-part-7-static-properties-and-methods/

Comment: Thank you, CBroe, for the link.  I actually used that same post to create my program shown above.  The problem is that each individual fish might be moving forwards or backwards so there will be 2 images for each class.  Each individual object needs a variable to determine which class image is used for its display.  I need something like a pointer I think.  That way each object has a pointer which points to one of two static, class-wide variables and when those static variables change all of the objects change accordingly.  This pointer would need to be used in the generic Fish print method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var fish = {
    print: function (cnv, x, y) {
        cnv.drawImage(this.pic, x, y);
    }
}

var clownF = Object.create(fish, {
    pic: { value: new Image() }
});

// define onload here before you set src.

clownF.pic.src = "clownF.png";
```

If you want to create more clownFs (like during the onload method) you can use Object.create with clownF as the prototype (first argument).

**Edit:**

If you want to the fish to be different sizes, you could add a width and height parameter to print():

```
var fish = {
    print: function (cnv, x, y, width, height) {
        cnv.drawImage(this.pic, x, y, width, height);
    }
};
```

Alternatively, you could make x, y, width and height properties of each fish and reference them with this. :

```
var fish = {
    print: function (cnv) {
        cnv.drawImage(this.pic, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
};

var fish1 = Object.create(clownF, {
    pic: new Image(),
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 100,
    height: 50
});
```

Regarding your above comment, If you want to be able to use two images for each fish and have them configurable, you could do this:

```
var fish = {
    print: function (cnv, x, y) {
        if(this.forward) {
            cnv.drawImage(this.forwardPic, x, y);
        } else {
            cnv.drawImage(this.backwardPic, x, y);
        }
    }
}

var clownF = Object.create(fish, {
    forwardPic: { value: new Image() },
    backwardPic: { value: new Image() }
});

clownF.forwardPic.src = "forwardClownF.png";
clownF.backwardPic.src = "backwardClownF.png";

var fish1 = Object.create(clownF, {
    forward: true
});
var fish2 = Object.create(clownF, {
    forward: false
});
```

If you want all clown fish to change direction at once, you could move the "forward" variable into the clownF object:

```
var clownF = Object.create(fish, {
    forwardPic: { value: new Image() },
    backwardPic: { value: new Image() },
    forward: true
});
```

If you want all fish to change at once you could add it to the Fish object.

```
var fish = {
    print: function (cnv, x, y) {
        if(this.forward) {
            cnv.drawImage(this.forwardPic, x, y);
        } else {
            cnv.drawImage(this.backwardPic, x, y);
        }
    },
    forward: true
}
```

If both the forward and backward images are the same, you could just use one image and flip it:

```
var fish = {
    print: function (cnv, x, y) {
        if(this.forward) {
            cnv.drawImage(this.pic, x, y);
        } else {
            cnv.save();
            cnv.scale(-1, 1);
            cnv.drawImage(this.pic, x, y);
            cnv.restore();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, bwroga, for the suggestion.  I still have the same problem for some reason.  Both fish appear the same size.  I had to assign the src before calling onload or else nothing appeared.

Comment: Thank you, bwroga, for all your help.  I greatly appreciate it.